# disable caching for a component in Symfony

Tags: symfony1

How can I disable caching for a component which I use on my Home Page. The component shows random items from database.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your module's cache.yml file:

```
_mycomponent:
  enabled: off
```

Comment: As caching for Home Page is enabled, that is why this doesn't work for me. Any other ideas.

Comment: Hmm, you could add a random cache key to the component, but it's not the greatest solution since that will generate a cache file everytime the component is called. Let me do some testing and see if i manage to came up with something.